# How can I adapt my PDFView to display in dark mode?

Tags: ios, swiftui, pdfkit, pdfview

I am using PDFView (Representable) in a SwiftUI project to display documents that are black text on a white background.

When in dark mode I want to be able to invert the colors so they appear as white text on a black background.

I don't see any way to change the text color or page color in the PDFView so was wonding if there is any other way I can get the entire view to just invert it's colors?

```
struct PDFKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let uRL: URL

    init(_ uRL: URL) {
        self.uRL = uRL
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitView>) -> PDFKitView.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.uRL)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfView.tintColor = .red
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitView>) {

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example", withExtension: "pdf")!
        PDFKitView(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: use a metal shader in swiftui